# Python, Pandas: check each element in list values of column to exist in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, mapping

I have dataframe column with values in lists, want to add new column with filtered values from list if they are in other dataframe.

df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,5,7,9],'b':[[10,1,'xxx'],[],[1,2,3],[5],[25,27]]})
```

```
**a**|**b**
:-----:|:-----:
1|[10, 1, 'xxx']
2|[]
5|[1, 2, 3]
7|[5]
9|[25, 27]
```

df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'d':[324,21,4353,345,4535,23],'e':[5,1,23,25,25,'xxx']})
```

I need to add new column with filtered column `b` in `df` so that it contains lists with only elements which are in `df2` column `e`.

Result:

```
**a**|**b**|**c**
:-----:|:-----:|:-----:
1|[10, 1, 'xxx']|[1,'xxx']
2|[]|[]
5|[1, 2, 3]|[1]
7|[5]|[5]
```

Speed is crucial, as there is a huge amount of records.

What I did for now:

1. created a set of possible values

```
l = list(df2['e'].unique())
```

2. Try to use `df.assign` with comprehensive lists, but it's not quite working and too slow.

```
df.assign(mapped=[[x for x in row if x in l] for row in df.b])
```

Appreciate any help.

#### UPD

In lists and df2 not always integer values, sometimes it's strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try casting to `str` and then `series.str.findall`

```
l = map(str,df2['e'].unique())
df['c'] = df['b'].astype(str).str.findall('|'.join([fr"\b{i}\b" for i in l]))
```

or shorter on the findall pattern courtesy @[Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12833166/shubham-sharma):

```
l = map(str,df2['e'].unique())
df['c'] = df['b'].astype(str).str.findall(fr"\b({'|'.join(l)})\b")
```

---

```
print(df)

   a             b     c
0  1  [10, 1, 100]   [1]
1  2            []    []
2  5     [1, 2, 3]   [1]
3  7           [5]   [5]
4  9      [25, 27]  [25]
```

Comment: Sorry, did not mentioned  - it's not exactly int values, sometimes strings, sometimes float/int as string. So better to consider everything as a string.

Comment: @Oleksii if everything is a string and assuming the lists are proper lists not string representation of a list:  use  `l = df2['e'].unique()` and `df['c'] = df['b'].astype(str).str.findall(fr"\b({'|'.join(l)})\b")` , but if you have mixed dtypes you still need the earlier answer with casting to string

Comment: Yes, thanks! Could you help please modify to store results in column c not as listy, but string comma-separated?

Comment: @Oleksii `.map(','.join)` after the code of the last line? `df['b'].astype(str).str.findall(fr"\b({'|'.join(l)})\b").map(','.join)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.intersect1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) as follows:

```
l = df2['e'].unique()     # unique() already returns ndarray, no need to use list()

df['c'] = df['b'].map(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x, l))


print(df)

   a             b     c
0  1  [10, 1, 100]   [1]
1  2            []    []
2  5     [1, 2, 3]   [1]
3  7           [5]   [5]
4  9      [25, 27]  [25]
```

### Edit

According to OP's edit on mixed type data, we just need to modify the way the unique values of column `e` of `df2` is extracted.  No need to change the main code of creating column `c`.

```
l = list(map(str, df2['e'].unique()))        # only change this

df['c'] = df['b'].map(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x, l))
 

print(df)


   a             b         c
0  1  [10, 1, xxx]  [1, xxx]
1  2            []        []
2  5     [1, 2, 3]       [1]
3  7           [5]       [5]
4  9      [25, 27]      [25]
```

Comment: nice , havent tested but I assume this can be faster than mine because of the string casting overhead.

Comment: Sorry, did not mentioned - it's not only int values, sometimes strings, sometimes float/int as string.

Comment: @Oleksii  my solution using numpy functions has no assumption of data types whether strings, int or float or even mixed types and numpy also supoorts these types.  And I don't need any type casting.  So, no problem.

Comment: Solution is super cool, no doubts. 
But for mixed types I'm receiving error: "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'". Could you check with updated dataframes in question?

Comment: @Oleksii  Fine-tuned the solution to support your edit on mixed types.

Comment: @anky, @SeanBean  Surprizingly, solution with `np.intersect1d` is much slower than first one with `findall`.   
46.1 ms vs 6.73 ms..

Comment: @Oleksii  Oh, normally numpy functions should run fast.  In this case, probably because we need to interface between Pandas and numpy and the map() function just iteratively call `np.intersect1d` without optimized vectorized operations.  I tried to call it another way as `np.intersect1d(df['b'], l)` but it seems it doesn't accept the series as it is 2D rather than 1D with list as elements.   Go ahead using the faster one.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have worked on a similar problem where I need to fetch rows containing a value we are looking for, but the data frame's columns' values are in the list format.

This is the solution I have come up with.

`fetched_rows = df.loc [ df['column_name'].map( lambda  x : True if check_element in x else False) ==  True ]`

Where
**column_name** ---> the column name that we need to look into

**check_element** ---> the value that we use to check whether it exists.